# Checking for attachments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Prior to submitting a form, I would like to check if a file has been attached  and pop up a warning message saying that a file needs to be attached if it hasn't been. I was wondering how to accomplish this using JavaScript or Prototype or JQuery etc?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are using an `<input type="file">` field, you can simply check if the element's value is a non-empty string:

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="file" id="attachment" />
   <input type="button" onClick="checkAttachment();" value="Send" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function checkAttachment() {
      if (document.getElementById('attachment').value !== '') {
         alert('File Attached');
      }   
      else {
         alert('No File Attached');
      }
   }
</script>
```